# Out of memory exception

Tags: wpf, exception, memory

When loading a flash file of size 70MB and above in a WPF app it works successfully for one or 2 times and then it starts throwing `OutofMemoryException`.
But when loading small flash files which are 10MB to 20 MB it always works successfully.
Here are the steps that we are following:

1. `ReadAllbytes` of a flash file.
2. Create `MemoryStream` instance from above step
3. Use f-in-box flash component and pass the `MemoryStream` as argument.

Just wondering if any one has any suggestions.
Thanks
N

Comment: It sounds like you're not disposing something, based on your comment that it's also causing Visual Studio VM problems.

Comment: Here is what i am doing:
Step 1: Open Main/Parent window.
Step 2: When you click on a button Open a child window as a dialog
Step 3: When you click on a button in child window, 
open a grandchild window as a dialog

In the grandchild window i also have subscribed to Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted.

However i have noticed that this event in the grandchild window gets called only when the Main/Parent window gets closed.
This is probably the reason why i am getting OOM exceptions.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 0):

Are you clearing the object after it is created?  I'm not a WPF guy but in asp.net when I create an object and forget to close it, the next time it's loaded, another instance is created.  This can chew up memory very quickly if the file is 70MB

Comment: Yes, i call both close and dispose of memorystream.

Comment: I have also noticed that VS 2008 continously gives this error message every alternate time i build the solution. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks